# How to join a number of threads which don't stop in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread

In C++ I have an std::vector of threads, each running a function running forever [while(true)].
I'm joining them in a for loop:

```
for (auto& thread : threads) 
{
    thread.join();
}
```

When the program finishes I'm getting a std::terminate() call inside the destructor of one of the threads. I think I understand why that happens, except for the first thread the other join calls don't get called.

What is the correct way of joining those threads?
And is it actually necessary to join them? (assuming they are not supposed to join under normal circumstances)

Comment: You are showing a correct way to join the threads.  You are not showing the cause of `std::terminate` (this is not a [mre]).  It's possible that a thread was already joined.  It's possible that you are calling this code from one of the threads being joined.

Comment: You need some way to tell the threads to stop, so the actually can be joined before the process exits. If the threads runs infinitely, they won't exit, and the `join` call will block.

Comment: if you can use C++20, there is `std::jthread` with some mechanism to stop it in a controlled way. If not you should turn your `while(true)` into some `while(should_keep_running)` via condition variables or similar

Comment: no thread really runs forever. Imho `while(true)` is poor design that needs to be fixed

Comment: @DrewDormann the reason for the std::terminate is that the thread is joinable, as seen in the std::thread destructor: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/~thread/

Comment: @OmerKawaz except that the code is stuck on the first `join()`, so there is no chance of any thread destructor being reached.

Comment: Why are the threads running forever? Wouldn't it be reasonable to let them finish when you are about to exit the program. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/1GE9TzG11)

Comment: TLDR: `t.join()` waits for thread `t` to stop. It doesn't do anything else. If the thread never stops, then `t.join()` will never return.

Comment: Regardless of what the answers say, please don't use *detach* unless you are manually controlling the thread's termination by other means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the threads cannot be joined because they never exit then you could use `std::thread::detach` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach). Either way before joining you should always check `std::thread::joinable` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/joinable).

The `std::terminate` is indeed most likely due to a running thread being destroyed and not being detached or joined before that. Note however that what happens to detached threads on application exit is implementation defined. If possible you should probably change the logic in those threads to allow graceful exit (`std::jthread` or `std::atomic` could help make stoppable threads):

EDIT:
Semi-complete C++17 "correct" code:

```
std::atomic stop{false};
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
threads.emplace_back(std::thread{[&] { while (!stop.load()) { /* */ }}});
threads.emplace_back(std::thread{[&] { while (!stop.load()) { /* */ }}});

//...

stop.store(true);

for (auto& thread : threads) 
{
    if (thread.joinable())
    {
        thread.join();
    }
}
```

Semi-complete C++20 "correct" code:

```
std::vector<std::jthread> threads;
threads.emplace_back(std::jthread{[] (std::stop_token stopToken) { while (!stopToken.stop_requested()) { /* */ }}});
threads.emplace_back(std::jthread{[] (std::stop_token stopToken) { while (!stopToken.stop_requested()) { /* */ }}});
```

The C++20 `std::jthread` allows functions that take `std::stop_token` to receive a signal to stop. The destructor `std::~jthread()` first requests stop via the token and then joins so in the above setup basically no manual cleanup is necessary. Unfortunately only MSVC STL and `libstdc++` currently support it while Clang's `libc++` does not. But it is easy enough to implement yourself atop of `std::thread` if you'd fancy a bit of exercise.

Comment: Detached threads opens up a whole new can of worms though

Comment: @TedLyngmo Indeed hence my suggestion to redesign the logic and make them gracefully exit. `std::jthread` comes to mind or simple `std::atomic` as a signal to exit in a loop.

Comment: I would hesitate to suggest the use of detach. It encourages bad practice.

Comment: @Galik I used to agree but I have come across legitimate use cases. For example when using `std::cin`. If there is no input It cannot be interrupted/cancelled and there is no timeout. So even if you have graceful stopping logic it would never get a chance to be used. Detaching and letting the OS kill it at the end is the only option. Non-blocking IO with just STL is borderline impossible.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the correct way of joining those threads?

Your way is fine, depending on what you're trying to do.

> And is it actually necessary to join them?

Yes. And no.

See, the main issue with `std::thread` is that you need to clean them up or they'll "do bad things" (TM), but joining them is only one way of cleaning them up. The other way is to simply detach them from your actual threads, if you don't care to control them anymore (which seems to be the case?).

The things you need to ask yourself is if your setup makes sense, where you create a whole bunch of threads that don't end cleanly but instead are interrupted randomly by your entire process dying. What happens to the work they were supposed to do? If they write their output somewhere and it's interrupted half way through, are you, your employers and your customers okay with file corruption?